# Double buffering in delphi not enough

Tags: delphi, flicker, double-buffering

I am trying to build an avionic attitude indicator with Delphi XE2.

[image]

I am using tRotateimage for the horizon
http://www.delphiarea.com/products/delphi-components/rotateimage/

[image]

This is behind a regular image which has transparent section in the middle.

[image]

Being able to rotate the image for roll and move the tRotateimage.top for pitch works well but I am getting a lot of flickering event with double buffered turned on my form. It flickers when I rotate the image or when I move it up via .top

Is there something else I can do to eliminate this flickering?

```
 if tryStrToFloat(GetHashtag('#ROLL',',',Memo1.Lines.Text),MyDouble) then
 Begin
  rtAttitudeNeedle.Angle := 0- MyDouble;
  rtAttitude.Angle :=0- MyDouble;
 end;

 if tryStrToFloat(GetHashtag('#PITCH',',',Memo1.Lines.Text),MyDouble) then
 Begin
  rtAttitude.Top := Round(iAttitudeTop + MyDouble);
 end;
```

Comment: This is probably something that the author of that control has to fix (or you if you have access to its source code).

Comment: Hello Andreas. I actually tried to do this using a regular Timage and it didn't flicker. I couldn't rotate it but I was able to simulate the pitch. I don't have the code for this unfortunately and its not being updated... Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Turns out I can get the code from the link afteral...

Comment: Off topic, but you do know that `-` can also be used as the *unary* minus sign? Hence, you can (and should) write `Angle := -MyDouble` instead of `Angle := 0 - MyDouble`.

Comment: yes. that shouldn't be there. I had a value in there before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double buffering a form is not always the magic trick to solve all your flicker problems.
you need to understand why you are having that flicker in the first place.

if you use the canvas object directly a lot in the paint routine, then you are doing nothing.

Most the time to solve this problem and reduce the flicker, you need to draw on a memory bitmap then at last `CopyRect` that to your canvas object.

Something like this for your component (Replace the `Paint` procedure with this code)

```
procedure TRotateImage.Paint;
var
  SavedDC: Integer;
  PaintBmp: TBitmap;
begin
  PaintBmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    PaintBmp.SetSize(Width, Height);

    if not RotatedBitmap.Empty then
    begin
      if RotatedBitmap.Transparent then
      begin
        PaintBmp.Canvas.StretchDraw(ImageRect, RotatedBitmap);
      end
      else
      begin
        SavedDC := SaveDC(PaintBmp.Canvas.Handle);
        try
          SelectClipRgn(PaintBmp.Canvas.Handle, ImageRgn);
          IntersectClipRect(PaintBmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Width, Height);
          PaintBmp.Canvas.StretchDraw(ImageRect, RotatedBitmap);
        finally
          RestoreDC(PaintBmp.Canvas.Handle, SavedDC);
        end;
      end;
    end;
    if csDesigning in ComponentState then
    begin
      PaintBmp.Canvas.Pen.Style := psDash;
      PaintBmp.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
      PaintBmp.Canvas.Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);
    end;

    Canvas.CopyRect(ClientRect, PaintBmp.Canvas, PaintBmp.Canvas.ClipRect);
  finally
    PaintBmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

if this does not solve the problem entirely then you could take a look at this flicker free set of components and try to adapt the rotating code you have on one of his components or inherit from it (I'm not the author and he is the one claiming flicker free functionality).

the [FreeEsVclComponents](https://github.com/errorcalc/FreeEsVclComponents) GitHub repository

**Edit:** after debugging I found a lot of problems with that control, so I decided to go with my recommendation to you.

I created the following control for you

[image: A gif image for TAttitudeControl]

All what I did is that inheriting from `TEsImage` and doing some changes to the way it work. From the old control I used the routine below to do the rotation transformation.

```
function CreateRotatedBitmap(Bitmap: TBitmap; const Angle: Extended; bgColor: TColor): TBitmap;
```

As you can see in the gif above the rotation routine is not perfect. I suggest you look for an alternative.

I also forked the repository of FreeEsVclComponents and added the `TAttitudeControl` to the `Es.Images` unit, so you have all what you need to install the control in your system. [Click here](https://github.com/GaNacereddine/FreeEsVclComponents)

At last I tested this on Tokyo and from the readme of the repository it should work on XE2 without problems.

**Edit2:** I changed the `CreateRotatedBitmap` with a better one (based on the GDI+), this is the result:

[image: TAlttitudeControl gif image]

I already pushed the changes to Github so you can git the code from there.
I'm adding the code here as well in case Github goes down (highly unlikely :))

```
uses
  WinApi.Windows, WinApi.GDIPApi, WinApi.GDIPObj, Vcl.Graphics, System.Types;

function RotateImage(Source: TBitmap; Angle: Extended; AllowClip: Boolean): TBitmap;
var
  OutHeight, OutWidth: Integer;
  Graphics: TGPGraphics;
  GdiPBitmap: TGPBitmap;
begin

  if AllowClip then
  begin
    OutHeight := Source.Height;
    OutWidth := Source.Width;
  end
  else
  begin
    if (Source.Height > Source.Width) then
    begin
      OutHeight := Source.Height + 5;
      OutWidth := Source.Height + 5;
    end
    else
    begin
      OutHeight := Source.Width + 5;
      OutWidth := Source.Width + 5;
    end;
  end;

  Result := TBitmap.Create;
  Result.SetSize(OutWidth, OutHeight);

  GdiPBitmap := nil;
  Graphics := TGPGraphics.Create(Result.Canvas.Handle);
  try
    Graphics.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeDefault);
    Graphics.SetPixelOffsetMode(PixelOffsetModeHalf);
    Graphics.SetInterpolationMode(InterpolationModeLowQuality);

    Graphics.TranslateTransform(OutWidth / 2, OutHeight / 2);
    Graphics.RotateTransform(Angle);
    Graphics.TranslateTransform(-OutWidth / 2, -OutHeight / 2);

    GdiPBitmap := TGPBitmap.Create(Source.Handle, Source.Palette);
    try
      Graphics.DrawImage(GdiPBitmap, 0, 0);
    finally
      GdiPBitmap.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Graphics.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Hello. I tried to cut and paste your code into the component and reload the package but it didn't work. It crashes when I drop the component on the form. Not sure why.

Comment: @EDemers I'm debugging the control now and I'm seeing a lot of problems, The Paint routine is called multiple times. I will see why and get back to you.

Comment: That is very nice of you. I am also trying on my side without success.

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately, the component won't install on my XE2. Its having issues with ES.Core.Classes.pas which uses: A := VersionStr.Split(['.']); and Major := A[0].Trim.ToInteger; giving the following errors: String does not contain a member called Split or Trim...

Comment: @EDemers if that is the only error then you could safely comment those lines out. you do not need them.

Comment: I had to comment out the label component for it to compile. I tried your attitude control. It doesn't flicker anymore. The image rendering is not super sharp compared to the Trotateimage but at least its not flickering anymore. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Works perfectly. I am sure a lot of other people will benefit from your work. I couldn't locate the code change. which .pas is it in?

Comment: @EDemers it is in EsGdiplus.pas you can see every thing I did from the dif view in github I encourage you to download GMaster a git GUI client and browse the branch explorer it is a blessing. You will see all the changes I did